# Swapping and Changing scripts

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, indexof, lastindexof

Hello my task is to swap the first and last words and capitalize the first letter of the first word

Say i input

**one two three four**

My output turns out to be

**fourTwo three fourone**

Here is my code
I am a beginner so please be easy

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tryNumber2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any line with no punctuation");
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        // First word to the end and capitalize.
        {
            int spacePosition = line.indexOf(" ");
            String FirstWord = line.substring(0, spacePosition).trim();
            String MiddleOfSentence = line.substring(spacePosition, line.length()).trim();
            String FirstChar = MiddleOfSentence.substring(0, 1);
            FirstChar = FirstChar.toUpperCase();
            MiddleOfSentence = FirstChar + MiddleOfSentence.substring(1, MiddleOfSentence.length());
            String LastWord = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
            System.out.println(LastWord + MiddleOfSentence  + FirstWord);
            keyboard.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where my error is or if I'm forgetting something..

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter any line with no punctuation");
    //trim() removes all leading and trailing whitespaces in Java. This will be useful for
    //the check we will perform next
    String line = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
    int firstWordPos = line.indexOf(" ");
    String firstWord = line.substring(0,firstWordPos);

    int lastWordPos = line.lastIndexOf(" ");

    if (lastWordPos < 0)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    else if(firstWordPos != lastWordPos) {
        String lastWord = String.valueOf(line.charAt(lastWordPos + 1)).toUpperCase() +
                line.substring(lastWordPos + 2);

        String outputString = lastWord + " " + line.substring(firstWordPos+1, lastWordPos) + " " + firstWord;
        System.out.println(outputString);
    }
    else {
        String lastWord = String.valueOf(line.charAt(lastWordPos + 1)).toUpperCase() +
                line.substring(lastWordPos + 2);

        String outputString = lastWord + " " + line.substring(0, lastWordPos);
        System.out.println(outputString);
    }
    keyboard.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Kinda works but then it doesnt swap first and last words

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you just had to append the last word and capitalize it. I read your question wrong. Fixed my code in the OP!